# Lean pass type as parameter

Tags: type-theory, lean

I am trying to do some category theory in Lean. However, I am not yet very fluent in type theory, and the following does not really seem to work:

```
class pset (S: Type) :=
(point: S)

class category (: Type) :=
(test: unit)

instance pset_category : category pset :=
{
  test := ()
}
```

I get a type mismatch at `category pset`, since `pset` has type `Type -> Type`, whereas it is expected to have type `Type`. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want `pset` to be something like "pointed sets". So then its definition should be

```
class pset :=
(S : Type)
(point : S)
```

Now you will notice that `#check pset` tells you it has type `Type 1`. So you still can't make it into a `category`, since you only defined "small" categories. If you change `Type` to `Type*` in the definition of `category`, all should be good.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the purpose mentioned in the question, it seems to work. However, now I am stuck at another point and I think it has something to do with this. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67124674/lean-define-groups)